# Library Reference Issues, VBA Excel 16.0, Project 14.0

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

My client recently migrated from 32-bit Excel 2016 to 64-bit Excel under Office 365 and retained 32-bit MS Project Standard 2010.

I have VBA code native to MS Project Standard 2010 which manipulates the Excel 2016 Application by early binding via the Excel 16.0 Object Library reference.  Following migration of Excel to the Office365 64-bit version the library reference to it (in MS Project Standard 2010) is no longer available.  It is not **MISSING** it is just not available in the list.  It won't even load by GUID.  I don't have admin rights and can't inspect or edit the registry.  My IT support explained that the issue is *probably* because we are mixing 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

I have worked round the issue by converting code from Early-binding to Late-binding.  I probably didn't catch everything (I have created a very lot of code in a very lot of application tools) and my concern is that some feature of my code that has not been converted correctly may not be discovered for some time.

My question is, should the Project 2010 application (Project 14.0) be able to make reference to the 64-bit Excel 16 under Office365 Object Library?  If so, what should my IT support guy be looking at to fix the problem please?

If the answer really is no I will just have to stick with the late-binding and do some extensive testing.

Comment: Thanks PEH for adding the missing tags, I'm grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cross-reference between 64-bit libraries and 32-bit libraries in the same host. The host can only use libraries of the same bitness. Late-binding won't help you in this situation - it helps you where there are version mismatching but not when bitness don't match.

If you need to continue automation between Project and Excel, then you may need to have a 32-bit Excel installation, or consider installing 64-bit Project. There's the third option of shelling out to VBScript or Powershell and running it out of process but that can be a lot of work.

Comment: That was a super-quick answer, thanks!  Late binding *seems* to have overcome the issue, perhaps because I am creating the 64-bit object from the 32-bit application and only using objects in the 64-bit application that were created by the 32 bit application?  I create Workbooks, Worksheets, Pivottables, PivotCharts, create code modules and add code from strings - all with no apparant issue.  Is there likely to be a reliability issue?

Comment: Something's not right because it should be literally impossible to use wrong bitness library in-process. You can interact using interprocess communication (e.g. running it out of process) but certainly not in process. Can you double check you are in fact using 64-bit or 32-bit for both applications?

Comment: Will do!  (I thought I was certain but will confirm - I'll need to get some time with my user!)

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that using late binding my 32-bit MS Project Standard 2010 application VBA code successfully created an Excel 64-bit application object, Workbook and Worksheet Objects writing to them source data and creating pivottables and charts.  My 32-bit vba project also created a code module in the 64 bit excel workbook object and added code to that created module.  However, on occasion the code module was created but could not be accessed - overcome by instead placing all code in the "ThisWorkbook" object in the 64-bit Excel object.  Not ideal, but repeatable.

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.9126.2282) 64-bit reported by the Excel instance,  Microsoft Project Standard 2010 Version 14.0.7214.5000 (32-bit) reported by the Project instance